# Unexpected token . on Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm using javascript to sort some data. I tested it on some versions of Chrome (86.0.4240.198), Chromium (80.0.3987.0) and Firefox (83.0) and it is working as expected.

```
const sortName = name => (a, b) => a[name]?.localeCompare(b[name]);
data.sort(sortName('name'));
...
// another sorting methods
...
```

But when I try it on my client Chrome version (69.0.3497.92 (Official Build) 32-bit), I receive this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

I cant upgrade their Chrome version, unfortunately. Why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: _“Why this is happening”_ - because optional chaining wasn’t supported yet in that massively outdated Chrome version - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: You can't not update your browser for 2 years and expect things to keep working smoothly! The answer is - Upgrade their chrome or it won't work, or don't use features that are not supported since version 69

Comment: @AlonEitan OP can't update their customer's browser ...

Comment: Yes, that's why I also suggested to NOT use  features that are not supported since version 69. I just don't understand what type of miracle answer the OP expects

Comment: @AlonEitan Yeah, sure. A few years ago I developed a result table for a long running fishing contest having extremely complex rules to calculate the points. After the contest was started, a week a or so, a participant called me, and said the table calculates the points incorrectly. I had tested the algorithm with a dozen of different browsers, and it was working well. It appeared, that the participant had an old tablet with Chrome version 11 installed (in 2018!), which treated `null` values in an array differently when sorting. We really can't choose which browsers visitors are using = ).

Comment: @AlonEitan a lot of times in enterprise scenarios there are lots of hurdles to updates like these (automations etc being one of them). I do not understand why is it so hard to respond in a non degrading way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @CBroe mentioned in the comments, **optional chaining (`?.`) isn't supported in chrome versions < 80**. It became available after version 80.

Please check [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining) or [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for further browser support.

---

[image: MDN docs]